# Postman: Test to check the number of response body lines

Tags: api, testing, postman, web-api-testing, postman-testcase

looking at the provided screenshot
[image]

In the response at Pretty section, I have 36 lines of data.
I would like to write a test for this request, which would check if the response body lines were 36 each time the request is run.
What would be your suggested test code for this test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Here's my solution:

```
let text = pm.response.text();
let lines = text.split("\n");
let length = lines.length;
pm.expect(length).to.eql(36);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @eerriicc , 
I am getting the following error when I try to run your solution:
`"AssertionError: expected 1 to deeply equal 36"`
Any hints on what needs to be adjusted?

Comment: Did you check the body? What does it look like?

Comment: Hello eerriicc, I have managed to inspect the response body and make some more sense out of it. 
This is how my usually response body looks like:
` [ 
   { 
       "id": "11111x", `
        "userEmail": "user@mail.com",
        "name": "file.txt",
        "size": 13070,
        "type": ".txt",
        "sha256": "44C54.....",
        "createdOn": "date and time",
        "isDomain": false,
        "isPublic": false,
        "history": [],
        "properties": []
    }
] 
`

It seems that your script counts the square brackets and everything in them as 1 line.
Any hints?

Comment: Ah, you should have said that you're testing JSON  :-)
In that case both your question and my solution make little sense.
There are a couple of examples on the Postman site that show you how to test a JSON array, and that's what you should do. Checking the number of response lines for a block of JSON that could well be written on one single line makes no sense. Test the number of elements in the JSON array.
Or much better: Check what JSON values you are getting (for instance check that "isDomain" is false).